# Filemaker baseelements FTP change directory

Tags: curl, filemaker

I'm using the `Baseelement's` FTP options to upload a file to the server.

```
BE_FTP_Upload ( $url & test::data ; test::data ; $user ; $pwd )
```

My default directory is `/web` which is under root and the files are being uploaded to the `/web` directory which is fine.

Now, I'm trying to navigate one step backward to a directory. For this I'm using `CWD` command as following

```
BE_Curl_Set_Option ( "CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST" ; "CWD /ext/data/" )
```

It is not changing the directory at all. I'm not sure the method `CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST` is correct or not. Also Is there any other way to navigate to a directory backward (not forward. Usually `cd ../` will do, but I don't know how to give this in BE curl option) ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to set BE_Curl_Set_Option to

```
"nocwd " & $url & "/ext/data/"
```

and then run BE_FTP_Upload

also, you might try `singlecwd`

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found an answer. I specified the option in my url itself with `//` after the ftp url. It is working fine. So, there is no need to use `BE_Curl_Set_Option` at all.

```
Set variable[$url ; "ftp://xxxx.com//ext/data/"]
```